# Get value for a variable from user inside a module

Tags: variable-definitions, interactive

I am writing a module. When I run the module, I want it to ask for a variable, like I can in other programing languages such as C++ or Python.

For example, in C++:

```cpp
int i;
cout << "Please enter an integer value: ";
cin >> i;
```

I want something similar to the above in *Mathematica*.

Comment: How about `Input`?

Comment: That is good. How can I use `Input` iteratively? In order to input several variables at once.

Comment: You can insert a `List` inside the `Input[]` field and it will returns this list: `vars = Input[];` `Head@vars` will be a `List` if you provide `{something, something else}`.

Comment: Suggest you read this [tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/RequestingInput.html).

Comment: This [question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/33724/3066) is relevant, too.

Comment: I used `Input[]`. I take this as the answer.